Informatica Powercenter - Handle error in HTTP Transformation
In Informatica Powercenter, I want to handle error when calling an API with an HTTP Transformation.
For example, I have 10 lines in input. I will call the API 10 times to get the datas.
But when the API is not available, I have the followinf error
[ERROR] HTTP Invoker encountered an error while invoking the HTTP. Reason: Connection timed out after 60001 milliseconds

And there is no data in output of the HTTP Transformation. I want to handle this error (any error) so that I can insert my input date in a table to retry later.
How to do that ?
Also, is there a way to reduce the timeout ? 60 seconds is too long.
I have already set the following Custom Properties, which works to get the status of the http tansformation, but only when there is no error
IncludeErrorResponsesInHTTPTransformation=Yes;

